# Loop through email items in Outlook folder to copy each table to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This code is to iterate an Outlook folder to extract the table in each email to paste to Excel.

After executing the paste line Outlook will crash and auto restart.
The line of code that causes the loop to stop is `objExcelWorksheet.Paste`.

If I execute without the loop the table pastes. When in a loop it can't run the second time and crashes after pasting the first table in Microsoft Excel.

```
Sub ExportTablesinEmailtoExcel()
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim objTable As Word.Table
    Dim lTableCount As Long
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("some_email@some.com") ' folders of your current account
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Buyer advise (IO)")
    Set Item = objFolder.Items
    'Create a new excel workbook
    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
    objExcelApp.Visible = True

    For Each Item In objFolder.Items
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            ' ... do stuff here ...
            Item.UnRead = False
            'Get the table(s) in the selected email
            Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
            Set objWordDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
            lTableCount = objWordDocument.Tables.Count - 1
            'If there is only one table
            'Just copy it into the first worksheet
            Set objTable = objWordDocument.Tables(1)
            objTable.Range.Copy
        
            Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            objExcelWorksheet.Paste
            objExcelWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit
            Debug.Print Item.ConversationTopic
        End If
    Next
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you published your email in the code! • If you say the code stops, which error message do you get?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It doesn't show any error message instead the Microsoft Outlook will be restart after executing the paste line. I tried to comment out the paste line and the loop iterate correctly without any errors or restart issue. Is there any alternative to execute paste function?

Comment: Actually that sounds like a bug or corrupt installation. A force close of Outlook without error message should not happen. Make sure you update your office to the latest version, if that doesn't work you can try a re-install of office.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with Excel requires extreme care.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant

Sub ExportTablesinEmailtoExcel_WithCare()

    ' Interacting with Excel requires extreme care

    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim objTable As Word.Table

    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.mapiFolder

    Dim Item As Object

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objFolder = objNS.folders("some_email@some.com") ' folders of your current account

    Set objFolder = objFolder.folders("Buyer advise (IO)")

    'Create a new excel instance
    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcelApp.Visible = True

    For Each Item In objFolder.items

        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

            Item.UnRead = False

            'Get a table from the item in this iteration of the loop
            Set objMail = Item

            Set objWordDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

            'If there is only one table
            If objWordDocument.Tables.count = 1 Then

                'Just copy it into the first worksheet
                Set objTable = objWordDocument.Tables(1)
                objTable.Range.Copy

                'Create a new excel workbook
                Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add

                Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                objExcelWorksheet.Paste

                objExcelWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit

                Debug.Print Item.ConversationTopic

            End If

            ' Release memory. Apparently not reused in next iteration.
            Set objMail = Nothing
            Set objWordDocument = Nothing
            Set objTable = Nothing
            Set objExcelWorkbook = Nothing
            Set objExcelWorksheet = Nothing

        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```